# New Gradle dependency not added to project and external dependencies (VSCode)

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I've been having this issue on and off for the past few weeks after beginning to learn how to use Gradle.

I added the dependency to my build.gradle file

```
compile group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-all', version: '1.12', ext: 'pom'
```

I used VSCode's command palette to "refresh", cleaned the server workspace and ran gradle build but the new dependency does not show up in my "Project and External Dependencies" and I cannot import `org.apache.batik.*`

Hoping to find a fix for this in VSCode as I have seen some other IDE specific fixes.

Comment: Ok so I instead used  "compile 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-all:1.12' " and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that in the map notation you were specifying the `ext: 'pom'` part. This effectively told Gradle to *only* import the POM file and not treat the dependency as a regular one.

When you moved to the different notation, you did not keep that `pom` element in the coordinates and so you got the right behaviour.

Note: `compile` has been replaced by `implementation` for a while now and is even deprecated in Gradle 6.x. Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) for more information on this.